# Cardinality of a Complex Set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be open unit disc in $\Bbb C$ and $H(D)$ be collection of all holomorphic functions on it.  Let
$T=\{f\in H(D):f(\frac{1}{2})=f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{2},f(\frac{1}{4})=f(\frac{1}{5})=\frac{1}{4}.........f(\frac{1}{2n})=f(\frac{1}{2n+1})=\frac{1}{2n}........\}$ then how to prove that T is empty set?
If $S=\{f\in H(D):f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2},f(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{4}.........f(\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{1}{2n}........\}$ then S contains identity function but I understand how to prove T is empty?

Comment: Well, $S= \{ \mathrm{id}_D \}$. Since $T \subseteq S$ and $ \mathrm{id}_D \notin T$, necessarily $T$ is empty.

Comment: Is this the only way to prove this?

Comment: Yes: this is the only way to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $ f\in T,$ then $f(z)=z$ on a set with limit point in $D.$